# SenchaTouch PhoneGap Ext.regApplication is not a function?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am following the SenchaTouch/PhoneGap tutorial at http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/
I'm at the stage of initialising the SenchaTouch application, my HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/touch/sencha-touch.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/Viewport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.mainLaunch, false);
        </script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

but when I execute:

```
Ext.regApplication({
name: 'app',
launch: function() {
    console.log('launch');
}});
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Ext.regApplication({ name: 'app', launch: function() { console.log('launch'); } })')
line: 6
message: "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Ext.regApplication({↵    name: 'app',↵    launch: function() {↵        console.log('launch');↵    }↵})')"
stack: "eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵↵_evaluateAndWrap↵↵evaluate↵↵[native code]"
__proto__: Error
```

any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    launch: function() {}
});
```

instead of `Ext.regApplication`